# Lose events for extjs form

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4

I have a big form on extjs which opens in window, and, for speed reasons, i cache it in hidden panel. There is can be only one window at time, so the cached form  is single too. On show event  i add form to window, with no rendering and with suspendLayout option for form. On close event i move the form to hidden panel, with panels add method. I do not use remove method not for window not for panel. So, for several times all perfect, but after 3- 5 window openings form lose all of its events: buttons, comboboxes, triggers and other controls are not responding. Where is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know for certain but my theory is that the observable object that your listeners are setup on is garbage collected at some indeterminate time period of inactivity.

I have seen this occur on an object representing the body of an iframe that is watched from the  parent window.  Click events from the body will work for some time and then all events will stop.

One way to test the theory is to store object reference in a global variable - this is NOT what you want to do in any app but worth a try just to test.  Global vars are never garbage collected.